# Dialog onCreateDialog show error when pick up the DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-datepicker

My code is working fine in Activity but when i used this code in fragment its not override the method Dialog **onCreateDialog()** , its shows 'Method does not override the method from itssuperclass'.

**TestFragment.java:**

```
public class TestFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener{
private ImageView calendarOne_ime;
Context context;
private TextView tv_dateone;
private int myear;
private int mmonth;
private int mday;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;
TestFragment dialogFragment;


public TestFragment()
{
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_date_test, container, false);


     FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
     dialogFragment = new TestFragment ();

    calendarOne_ime = (ImageView)rootview. findViewById(R.id.cone);
    tv_dateone = (TextView)rootview. findViewById(R.id.dateone_txt);
    calendarOne_ime.setOnClickListener(this);

    return rootview;


}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.cone:
            setCurrentDateOnView();
            addListenerOnButton();
            break;
    }
}


public void setCurrentDateOnView() {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    myear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
}
public void addListenerOnButton() {
    getActivity().showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
}
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
    switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            DatePickerDialog _date =   new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), datePickerListener, myear,mmonth, mday){
                @Override
                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
                {
                    if (year < myear)
                        view.updateDate(myear, mmonth, mday);
                    if (monthOfYear < mmonth && year == myear)
                        view.updateDate(myear, mmonth, mday);
                    if (dayOfMonth < mday && year == myear && monthOfYear == mmonth)
                        view.updateDate(myear, mmonth, mday);
                } };
            return _date; }
    return null;
}
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        myear = selectedYear;
        mmonth = selectedMonth;
        mday = selectedDay;
        // set selected date into textview
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),new StringBuilder()  .append(mmonth + 1).append("-").append(mday).append("-") .append(myear).append(" "),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        tv_dateone.setText(new StringBuilder().append(mmonth + 1).append("/").append(mday).append("/").append(myear).append(" "));
    }
   };
 }
```

**xml code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/dateviewone_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.2"
    android:text="Area"

    android:gravity="center_vertical"

    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateone_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Date"

        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/appointment"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:layout_gravity="right"
        />





</RelativeLayout>
```

I also share the screen shot where i face the problem.[image]

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.pickcel.lite.agent.R;
import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class TestFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
    private ImageView calendarOne_ime;
    Context context;
    public static TextView tv_dateone;

    public TestFragment()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_payment, container, false);
        calendarOne_ime = (ImageView)rootview. findViewById(R.id.cone);
        tv_dateone = (TextView)rootview. findViewById(R.id.dateone_txt);
        calendarOne_ime.setOnClickListener(this);
        return rootview;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.cone:
                android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
                break;
        }
    }

  public static class SelectDateFragment extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
        populateSetDate(yy, mm+1, dd);
    }
    public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        tv_dateone.setText(month+"/"+day+"/"+year);
    }

   }
}
```

**Output:**
     [image]

[image]

Comment: its not working .. actually error is gone but date is not pick up.

Comment: @HarishRawal are you getting datapicker dialog

Comment: Please check updated answer i checked it's working..what you are doing is little wrong

Comment: if you have any issues let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169726/discussion-between-gowthaman-m-and-harish-rawal).

Comment: Its working. and also i have change the code not to select past date.

Comment: I appreciate you very much.

Answer (score 1):

**Make Dialog fragment abstract.Follow below code:**

```
public abstract class DialogFragment extends Fragment
```

**For Datepicker follow below code:**

**Only need to send context of fragment/activity and textview/editext on 
 which you need to open date picker.**

```
  public static void setDateFromDatePicker(Context context, TextView textView) {

        int mYear, mMonth, mDay;

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Launch Date Picker Dialog
        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(context,
                (view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth) -> {
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.LOCAL_DATE_FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH);
                    String formattedDate = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
                    textView.setText(formattedDate);
//                    textView.setText(String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        dpd.show();
    }
```